# How I can make my own command with arguments in cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

Something like `echo hello!`.

I made only a command that executes immutable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do so, using parameters. Say, you have a batchfile `say.bat` which is supposed to be your own implementation of `echo`, and you want to use it like `say hello world`.

```
@echo off
echo first parameter: %1
echo first parameter: %~1 (without quotes)
echo second parameter: %1
echo second parameter: %~1 (without quotes)
echo all paramters: %*
echo all paramters: %~* (doesn't work)
```

Try it with `say hello world`, `say "hello world"` `say "hello world" "hi you"`